# How to build only android core

Tags: android, android-source

I've faced with problem that on my phone alot of services running.

Is there any way to build Android image for Nexus4 **without** all preinstalled packages.

Default build
`./build/envsetup.sh`
`lunch full_mako`
`make -j32`

build image with preinstalled services.

Comment: Have you tried just doing `make mako` ?

Comment: And there are no other `mako` variants than `mako_full` if you run `lunch` without arguments?

Comment: Depending which version of aosp you are on, it will be lunch full_mako-user or full_mako-userdebug, or lunch aosp_mako-userdebug, etc. But that being said, what do you mean by preinstalled packages? You mean you don't want Camera? Settings? DeskClock?

Comment: @AndrewT. Exactly. I want to have only adb access to my phone. I don't want to have any graphics.

Answer (score 1):

You can pick and choose which packages are included in a build. Packages (apks) and libraries get added through various make files in via the variable PRODUCT_PACKAGES.

The easiest way to see this is to go into build/target/product/ and look at some of the make files in here. If you check out core.mk you will see that it is mostly just filled with adding various packages to every build.

In some cases these files can overlap, based on what kind of build you are making, but in order to have a build where there are no preinstalled services or packages, launcher or anything, I would start by determining which packages you need and don't need and cutting them out of these make files. Grep will be your friend here. Ultimately if you want to maintain this you will probably want to create a new build target which loads a different set of make files. This process will also involve a fair amount of trial and error.

Finally, make sure you call make installclean between builds.